# Get cookies from sessionvariable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Let's say I authenticate to a web site in powershell using invoke-websession, and I store the session in a variable :

```
$login=Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -Method Post -Body $data -SessionVariable mysession
```

Now let's say that for some reason I do not know the URL used in invoke-websession. But I know there is a coockie in the session variable :

```
$mysession.Cookies

                     Capacity                         Count                 MaxCookieSize             PerDomainCapacity
                     --------                         -----                 -------------             -----------------
                          300                             1                              4096                            20
```

How can I retrieve the URL from the cookie? The method getcookie requires the URL as mandatory argument :

```
$mysession.Cookies | gm


   TypeName : System.Net.CookieContainer

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Add               Method     void Add(System.Net.Cookie cookie), void Add(System.Net.CookieCollection cookies), void...
Equals            Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetCookieHeader   Method     string GetCookieHeader(uri uri)
GetCookies        Method     System.Net.CookieCollection GetCookies(uri uri)
GetHashCode       Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType           Method     type GetType()
SetCookies        Method     void SetCookies(uri uri, string cookieHeader)
ToString          Method     string ToString()
Capacity          Property   int Capacity {get;set;}
Count             Property   int Count {get;}
MaxCookieSize     Property   int MaxCookieSize {get;set;}
PerDomainCapacity Property   int PerDomainCapacity {get;set;}
```

Thanks for your ideas people

Comment: The original domain the cookie was retrieved from is not stored in `System.Net.CookieContainer`, but you can access the _cookie domain_ (that is, the domain scope of the cookie) via reflection. I can provide you with an demo code for that, but it's probably not what you looking for, is it?

Comment: I know old post and you might want something more generic but for your code example .did you try: `$mysession.Cookies.GetCookies($url)`